# Chaining Angular Filters in Javascript (not HTML)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, chaining

New to Angular, and I've found a lot of examples for using multiple Angular filters in HTML (with an ng-repeat) -- e.g. `{{item in items | filter:functionA | filter:functionB | etc... }}` -- but I can't find a good example for how to achieve that same filter chaining in Javascript.

I am currently achieving this with an overarching single function that cycles through filters -- e.g. (in Coffee Script)

```
$filter('filter')( places, placeFilters )

placeFilters: (place) ->
  result = place
  result = functionA(result)
  result = functionB(result)
  etc...
```

I am curious if there is a better (cleaner and more efficient) path?